# Submitting a Form with a Button

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I know this isn't really how `<button>` elements are supposed to be used, but is there a way to submit a form using buttons instead of `<input type="submit">`? I need to have buttons with two lines, and you can't do that with `<input>`s, but you can with `<button>`s.

Some jQuery method or something would work fine, I just hate having to use background images for these buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a `button` tag submit a form, like so:

```
<button type="submit"> This will submit! </button>

<button type="button"> This will NOT submit! </button>
```

Also, I believe the default varies per browser so I think a `button` tag should always have a `type` attribute just to be safe.

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks. I didn't know you could that. That's a really simple solution...can't accept for another 9 minutes, but as soon as I can I will...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

or

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go for the button/jQuery option this will do it:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function() {
    $('#theForm').submit();

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById["YOUR_FORMS_ID"].submit()
```

You just use the `.submit()` method of the DOM element of the form in javascript

So...

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById["YOUR_FORMS_ID"].submit()">CLICK TO SUBMIT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could technically submit with element if you bind a function to it.

For example, you could use a  by doing:

```
<form id="someForm">
    <span id="someSubmitEle">Here goes text</span>
</form>
...
$("#someSubmitEle").click(function(){$("#someForm").submit();});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's built-in submit() method should do the trick:
http://api.jquery.com/submit/

HTML would be something like:

```
...
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="someURL" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="textField1" value="TextValue" />
</form>

<button id="submitter" value="Two lines of text because it can I guess." />
...
```

And the jQuery would look something like:

```
$('#submitter').click(function() {
     $('#myForm').submit();
});
```